# SKTileMap getting Values from GKNoiseMap

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, perlin-noise, sktilemapnode

ive been following the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gknoisemap) on GKNoiseMaps and i managed to get an image to spawn and it looks really good

using this code here

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


class Noise: GKNoise {
    var NoiseSource = GKPerlinNoiseSource(frequency: 0.05, octaveCount: 3, persistence: 1, lacunarity: 1, seed: Int32(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(500 - 1))))
    override init(_ noiseSource: GKNoiseSource, gradientColors: [NSNumber : UIColor]) {
        super.init(NoiseSource, gradientColors: [ (+1.0 as NSNumber): UIColor.red, (-1.0 as NSNumber) : UIColor.black])
    }
}
let noise = Noise()
let Vector1 = vector_double2(1.0, 1.0)

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let NoiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: vector_double2(300.0, 300.0),
                              origin: vector_double2(0.0, 0.0),
                              sampleCount: vector_int2(100),
                              seamless: true)
    let texture = SKTexture(noiseMap: NoiseMap)
    let Node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

    Node.size = CGSize(width: 1000,height: 1000)
    Node.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    self.addChild(Node)
}

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

now how do i create a SKTileMap with this updated code here

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


class Noise: GKNoise {
    var NoiseSource = GKPerlinNoiseSource(frequency: 0.05, octaveCount: 3, persistence: 1, lacunarity: 1, seed: Int32(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(500 - 1))))
    override init(_ noiseSource: GKNoiseSource, gradientColors: [NSNumber : UIColor]) {
        super.init(NoiseSource, gradientColors: [(+1.0 as NSNumber): UIColor.red, (-1.0 as NSNumber) : UIColor.black])
    }
}
let noise = Noise()
let Vector1 = vector_double2(1.0, 1.0)

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let NoiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: vector_double2(300.0, 300.0),
                              origin: vector_double2(0.0, 0.0),
                              sampleCount: vector_int2(100),
                              seamless: true)
    let tileGroup = [SKTileGroup]()
    let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: tileGroup)
    let map = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: 10, rows: 10, tileSize: CGSize(width: 20,height: 20), tileGroupLayout: tileGroup)
}

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

and generate the SKTileMap with values from the GKNoiseMap as stated in the Apple Docs?

any help would be appreciated as i dont really know about SKTileMaps and how they work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an `SKTileDefinition` using the texture created from the `NoiseMap`. Then it's possible to paint this tile into the `SKTileMapNode` at any location. This example iterates through all columns and rows and sets the tile. I made the size of the NoiseMap 64 x 64 since that is a typical size for a tile.

```
override func sceneDidLoad() {
    let noise = Noise()
    let noiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: vector_double2(64.0, 64.0), origin: vector_double2(0.0, 0.0), sampleCount: vector_int2(100), seamless: true)
    let bgTexture = SKTexture(noiseMap: noiseMap)

    let bgDefinition = SKTileDefinition(texture: bgTexture, size: bgTexture.size())
    let bgGroup = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: bgDefinition)
    bgGroup.name = "noiseTest"

    let tileSet = SKTileSet(tileGroups: [bgGroup])

    let bgNode = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: 10, rows: 10, tileSize: bgTexture.size())
    let tile = bgNode.tileSet.tileGroups.first(where: { $0.name == "noiseTest" })

    for column in 0 ..< bgNode.numberOfColumns {
        for row in 0 ..< bgNode.numberOfRows {
            bgNode.setTileGroup(tile, forColumn: column, row: row)
        }
    }

    bgNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    bgNode.setScale(1)

    self.addChild(bgNode)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks i will test it. BTW my app launched today (it has nothing to do with this) and its called "Crappy Duck" and i would appreciate it if you could check it out

Comment: dude! it works! but i need to set the tiles based on the level of noise i am attempting to create a map based on the level of noise so the map has a bit of randomness to it

Comment: If you initialise the `SKTileGroup` using the init method `public init(rules: [SKTileGroupRule])` then you can specify an array of `SKTileDefinitions`. That should handle the randomness!

Comment: could you update your answer with an example so we dont get in trouble for  not being the correct answer

Comment: I think randomising an SKTileMapNode is a separate thing. You could try yourself, then ask another question.

Comment: oh. ok thanks for your help though! i will ask another question